Playing a video from Google Files on Android device with VideoView using Kotlin
I'm working on an Android app (API 33, Android 13.0) that displays a video depending on the selection made. I am able to play each video (.mp4) from the raw folder, but I'd like to store the videos on the Android device (a tablet, in this case), since I'll have about 50 videos (~25MB each). The tablet will not have internet when the app is running, so the videos need to be stored locally.
I found a few similar topics here, but I'm having a hard time understanding the solutions or work-arounds from 10+ years ago.
This is how I currently access the video. The WorkModel that is passed in includes the name of the video file.
val workPackage = intent.getParcelableExtra("work_package",WorkModel::class.java)
        if(workPackage != null){            
            val resId = resources.getIdentifier(workPackage.Video, "raw", packageName)
            val packageName = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + resId

            val uri = Uri.parse(packageName)
            videoView.setVideoURI(uri)

            val mediaController = MediaController(this)
            videoView.setMediaController(mediaController)

            videoView.start()
        }

How would I go about accessing the video if it were stored in Files? Or perhaps Drive? Is it as simple as modifying the URI?
I started reading here: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases#show-all-folder
Add declaration to app manifest: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/declaring
What kind of permissions would I need to request, if any? I only need read access. Is uses-permission-sdk-23 all I need?
DATA: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns#data
What would be the absolute filesystem path for Google Files or Google Drive? Or should I be using a different location?
---UPDATE---
So I put the video in Internal Storage -> Movies. When I clicked on "File Info", it showed me the path /storage/emulated/0/Movies/crystal.mp4, but now I'm not sure what to do with that information.
I tried the following with no success:
videoView.setVideoPath("/storage/emulated/0/Movies/crystal.mp4")

and
val packageName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().path + "/storage/emulated/0/Movies/crystal.mp4"
val uri = Uri.parse(packageName)

and
val packageName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().path + "/Movies/crystal.mp4"
val uri = Uri.parse(packageName)

---UPDATE 2---
I check if the path is valid with file.exists() and it appears to find it (ends in the if statement).
val packageName = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.crystal
val filePath = "/storage/emulated/0/Movies/crystal.mp4"
val file = File(filePath)
if (file.exists()) {
     //gets crystal video from res/raw which I know will play
     val uri = Uri.parse(packageName)
     videoView.setVideoURI(uri)
} else {
     //I know this will fail
     videoView.setVideoPath("/crystal.mp4")
}

If I try that same code with file.canRead(), it fails (ends in the else statement).
val packageName = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.crystal
val filePath = "/storage/emulated/0/Movies/crystal.mp4"
val file = File(filePath)
if (file.canRead()) {
     //gets crystal video from res/raw which I know will play
     val uri = Uri.parse(packageName)
     videoView.setVideoURI(uri)
} else {
     //I know this will fail
     videoView.setVideoPath("/crystal.mp4")
}

So that seems to suggest that the path is fine but I can't read the video file. Why would that be?
---UPDATE 3---
val filePath = "/storage/emulated/0/Movies/crystal.mp4"
val file = File(filePath)
if (file.exists()) {
     if (file.canRead()) {
          val asdf = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.crystal
          val uri = Uri.parse(asdf) //if exists and can read, play crystal from res/raw
          videoView.setVideoURI(uri)
     } else {
          val asdf = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.testvid
          val uri = Uri.parse(asdf) //if exists but can't read, play testvid from res/raw
          videoView.setVideoURI(uri)
     }
} else {
     val asdf = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.testvid1
     val uri = Uri.parse(asdf) //if doesn't exist, play testvid1 from res/raw
     videoView.setVideoURI(uri)
}

It plays testvid, which means the path exists but the file can't be read.
---UPDATE 4---
So I removed /crystal.mp4 from this line:
val filePath = "/storage/emulated/0/Movies/crystal.mp4"

And now file.exists() and file.canRead() both return true. I'm guessing that's because it's only looking at the folder and not the file?

if it were stored in Files?  ? In Files? What kind of location is that?

videoView.setVideoURI(uri) You can use the same. With an uri pointing to a file on storage.

The app "Google Files".

One cannot store files in an app. One stores files in a device on a storage location. Mostly external storage or removable micro-sd card. Please correct your post. Edit it.

Files is a file explorer/manager app. It shows the files which are on your device. It does not contain files.

Ok. I do have an SD card that I've been messing around with because it seems like that may be more straight-forward. I'm running into issues with it though. videoView.setVideoPath("/sdcard/crystal.mp4") doesn't seem to work. I'll do a bit more trouble-shooting and start a new question for that method if I can't figure it out.

With SD card you mear a removable micro-sd card? Or external storage? As /sdcard/ is not a removable micro-sd. So wrong path used.

Removable micro SD card that only contains one video at the moment.

I've tried several different paths but can't figure it out. New topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78359191/playing-a-video-from-removable-sd-card-on-android-device-with-videoview-using-ko

Updated main post above with status on using internal storage.

I told you before to use File.exists() and File.canRead() before you try to read from /storage/emulated/0/Movies/crystal.mp4.

val packageName Do not call that a package name. CommonsWare already told you not to do such nasty things.

File.exists() is successful. File.canRead() fails. See edits above.

There is no file.exists() in your code. Add it. Do it before canRead(). And remove packageName. And that else is nonsense so remove too.

Added update 3 above. It plays testvid, which means the path exists but the file can't be read.

That is terrible code with all those if else's. Unreadable code. I already asked you to remove the else and now you added another one.

if (! file.exists()) return; if (!file.canRead()) return; Before both returns you could Toast() the user to inform.

Did you request READ_MEDIA_VIDEOS permission?

Adding READ_MEDIA_VIDEO permissions didn't change the behavior. And I'm sorry if my code looks terrible to you. This is debug code, not final code. Right now it simply checks what I want it to check. Once it's functional, I can clean it up and optimize it.

Your coding is so confusing that you confuse yourself as nowhere you use setVideoUri to play your file. Or setVideoPath(). The whole problem is that you mess around with asdf which you better should have not even mentioned as it has nothing to do with your problem.
