Playing a video from removable SD card on Android device with VideoView using Kotlin
I'm working on an Android app (Lenovo tablet, API 33, Android 13.0) that displays a video depending on the selection made. I am able to play each video (.mp4) from the raw folder, but I'd like to store the videos removable micro SD card, since I'll have about 50 videos (~25MB each).
I am able to play a video stored in res/raw using the following code:
val packageName = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.crystal
val uri = Uri.parse(packageName)
videoView.setVideoURI(uri)
val mediaController = MediaController(this)
videoView.setMediaController(mediaController)
videoView.start()

Now I want to play the same video from a removable SD card:
Manifest
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Activity
val packageName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().path + "/crystal.mp4"
val uri = Uri.parse(packageName)
videoView.setVideoURI(uri)
val mediaController = MediaController(this)
videoView.setMediaController(mediaController)
videoView.start()   

This doesn't work. I get a pop-up that says "Can't play this video".
All the examples I have found online seem pretty straightforward, so I'm not sure why this isn't working. Is my path wrong? What am I missing?

but I'd like to store the videos on the Android device That does not match that you want to store them on a removable micro-sd card. They are not stored on the device then but on a card. Confusing writing.

First,packageName is a filesystem path, not a string form of a Uri. Use Uri.fromFile(), not Uri.parse(). Second, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() does not point to removable storage on most Android devices -- it points to the on-device storage. Third, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is for older devices, does not work on newer devices like yours, and would require additional code at runtime. You may not have arbitrary read access to removable storage on that hardware.

Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().path That has nothing to do with a removable micro sd card. That is for storage build into the device. So you better ask how to obtain a path to removable micro sd card. And once you know that path you first better use File.exists() and File.canRead() before you try to use the path of your file. An mp4 file is a media file so you can request access for it for Android 13+.

@CommonsWare
Use Uri.fromFile(), not Uri.parse(): But Uri.fromFile() requires type File, not type String. How do I change packageName to type File?
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() does not point to removable storage on most Android device: That's not what most of the examples I found online suggested, but most examples were old. I can't find any newer examples. What should I use instead?
You may not have arbitrary read access to removable storage on that hardware: So how do I know if I can access files on a removable SD card? Isn't that a common thing to do?

@VeronicaV: "How do I change packageName to type File?" -- the File constructor takes a String path. "What should I use instead?" -- you could try StorageManager and its getStorageVolumes() method. "So how do I know if I can access files on a removable SD card?" -- since it feels like you are building this app to run on one device (your Lenovo tablet), you can just see if you can get it to work. "Isn't that a common thing to do?" -- not in the way you are doing it. For example, out of a few billion phones, few will have crystal.mp4 in the root of an SD card, which your app assumes.

@CommonsWare, ok, thanks. I'm trying to see if I can get it to read from internal storage instead. I'm making a bit more progress there with the right file path. I just can't read from it yet and I'm not sure why. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78356830/playing-a-video-from-google-files-on-android-device-with-videoview-using-kotlin
